# Add axis to geographical plot in basemap/pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I've done some plots using pythons basemap. I want to provide some additional information to my plots, by adding the latitude and longitude as axes around my geographical plot. Preferably with tick marks thats pretty accurate. Just as a normal map.

Is this possible?

This is my plotting code:

```
map = Basemap(
projection="merc",
resolution = 'h', area_thresh = 0.001,
llcrnrlon=bottomlong, llcrnrlat=bottomlat,
urcrnrlon=toplong, urcrnrlat=toplat)
map.drawcoastlines(color='black')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`map.drawmeridians(meridians, ...)`](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/api/basemap_api.html#mpl_toolkits.basemap.Basemap.drawmeridians) for lines of longitude, and [`map.drawparallels(circles, ...)`](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/api/basemap_api.html#mpl_toolkits.basemap.Basemap.drawparallels) for lines of latitude.